# Not able to find a migrated dpcpp output file and dpct responds as "Migration not necessary"

Tags: intel-oneapi, intel-dpct

I am trying to migrate my cuda application using the dpct. When calling dpct; I see it processes CUDA files and generates some benign warnings but at the end it exits without writing out any DPC++ equivalent file.I can clearly see CUDA functions called in these applications and removal of CUDA path would fail the compile process.This is the command I used

> $ dpct --report-type=all --cuda-include-path=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/include -p compile_commands.json"

I have eliminated the actual physical paths to files to avoid confusion:

````
Processing: ....../ComputeThermoGPU.cu
Processing: ....../CommunicatorGPU.cu
Processing: ....../ParticleData.cu
Processing: ....../Integrator.cu
------------------APIS report--------------------
API name Frequency
------------------------------------------------- 
----------Stats report---------------
File name, LOC migrated to DPC++, LOC migrated to helper functions, LOC not needed to migrate, 
LOC not able to migrate
....../Integrator.cu, 1, 0, 168, 0
....../ParticleData.cu, 1, 0, 402, 0
....../ComputeThermoGPU.cu, 1, 0, 686, 0
....../ParticleGroup.cu, 6, 0, 111, 0
Total migration time: 17207.371000 ms
-------------------------------------
dpct exited with code: 1 (Migration not necessary)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I could get a solution to my own question
Use
`dpct -p compile_commands.json --in-root=src --out-root=dpct_out --process-all`

I think the reason might be, due to the absence of the driver code(containing main function), DPCT thinks that since these helper .cu files are not being utilized anyway, there is no need to perform migration on these files. That's the reason you see "Migration not necessary" warning.